# Open second activity after clicking a specific radio button, otherwise, show message

Tags: java, android

I am rather new to Android/Java programming and looking for some help with a very, very basic app that I am working with.  I am purely building this just to get used to Java coding and building applications for Droids, so bear with me.

I have 10 radio buttons grouped together and only one of them is the right answer (button #10).  If the user clicks on any of them 1-9 I have it displaying a message that says "sorry try again", but if they click on #10, I want it to take them to a new activity, namely a page where I will put up some graphics and text that says congraulations and things of that nature.  The buttons work fine for 1-9, but when I click on #10 I am gettinga  force close error.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    public class MainQuiz extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener, android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_quiz);
    ((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);}  

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {    
        String numeral = null;              
        if (checkedId == R.id.button1) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.button2) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.button3) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        }   
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button4) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } 
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button5) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } 
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button6) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } 
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button7) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } 
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button8) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } 
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button9) {
            numeral = "Nope, try again!";
        } 
        else if (checkedId == R.id.button10) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainQuiz.this, CorrectAnswer.class); 
            MainQuiz.this.startActivity(myIntent);


        } 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+numeral+"",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        }
```

Any help would be apprecitaed, I am sure this is a simple fix and I am sure it is something glaring in the syntax and code that I have messed up, but again, I am new :)

Thanks!

Here is the log after the Force Close:

```
11-14 13:56:48.982: D/AndroidRuntime(862): Shutting down VM
11-14 13:56:48.982: W/dalvikvm(862): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.quiz/com.test.quiz.CorrectAnswer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.quiz.CorrectAnswer
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.quiz.CorrectAnswer
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
11-14 13:56:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that what you've pasted isn't enough. Could you paste  the stack trace (The errors in red)?

Comment: How can I add what was in the Logcat to this question?  The comment field appears to be limited to 584 characters...?

Comment: Just add the part where its crashing-  the full exception trace.  Ignore the rest for now.

Comment: @user1824651: Edit your question and add in the stack trace. There should be an edit button next to the share button right below the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The force close will always put an exception stack trace in your logcat file.  Please put this in future posts, it tells us what line crashed and why.

My guess from your code and newness to Android-  you probably didn't add the CorrectAnswer activity to your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Unfortunately I did add the activity to the manifest file.  I tried doing my due diligence and looking up other topics before I posted my question, and that is one of the things I found :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your problem, but you can improve your code:
use "switch - case" construction.

```
switch (chekedId) {
        case R.id.button10:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainQuiz.this, CorrectAnswer.class); 
            startActivity(myIntent);
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nope, try again!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this line is probably what is causing your problems.

```
MainQuiz.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Remove the MainQuiz, and it should work

```
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it still behaves the same and crashes.  May I ask why you thought that was the culprit? Just curious to continue to enhance my own knowledge.

Comment: It's unusual to use Classname.this when you're not in a private subclass.  Not wrong I don't think, just oddlooking.

Answer (score 0):

```
MainQuiz.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

replace by

```
startActivity(myIntent);
```